# Error with `realloc()` with arraylist-like struct with two arrays

Tags: c, pointers, arraylist, struct, realloc

As part of a personal project, I'm trying to create a dynamic array of 2-tuples that show a) the line in a program and b) the number of bytecode tokens associated with that line. I've implemented this as a struct of arrays:

```c
typedef struct{
int count; // Number of elements
int capacity; // total capacity of arraylist
int* lines;
int* lineCount;
}
```

this is based on the example from the codebase, as such:

```c
int count;
int capacity;
uint8_t* bytes;
```

My problem comes from re-allocation - I have several helper functions/macros for growing and re-allocating the array lists memory - here particularly the macro GROW_ARRAY and reallocate(), as described below. When I try and re-allocate `lines`, it works fine, but I get a segmentation fault and `realloc(): invalid old size` several times when I attempt to reallocate lineCount after it

I'm using the code base from Bob Nystrom's Crafting Interpreters, especially this first part here https://craftinginterpreters.com/chunks-of-bytecode.html#challenges. Most of the code comes from there, albeit tinkered with some of having added

Mostly, I've added a lot of checks and been running this with all the debug features in gcc I can find. Notably, `realloc(): invalid old size` has stop appearing as I've tinkered with the code some. 
EDIT: Added main function that should reproduce behavior

```c
int main() {
    LineArray lines;
    // Initialize to 0 / NULL
    initLineArray(&lines);
    updateLineArray(&lines, 0, 1);
}
```

```c
// the structure I'm using

typedef struct {
int capacity;
int count;
int* lines;
int* lineCount;
} LineArray;

/* Note LineArray has already been initialized earlier with 
capacity=0;
count=0;
lines=NULL;
lineCount=NULL;

*/
void updateLineArray(LineArray* array, int line, int count) {

    // IF line in `lines` -- update it

    int index = containsLine(array, line);

    if (index != -1) { // IF Index is not Error Code
    // I think I fixed a bug here?
        array->lineCount[index] += count;
        return;
    } 

    //ELSE -- add line to end (naturally appends); then increment
    else {
        //Check to see if array would be overgrown
        if (array->capacity < array->count + 1) {
            //IF yes, regrow array
            int old_capacity = array->capacity;
            array->capacity = GROW_CAPACITY(old_capacity);

            // Reallocate arrays.
            array->lines = GROW_ARRAY(array->lines, int, old_capacity,
                                        array->capacity);

            array->lineCount = GROW_ARRAY(array->lineCount, int, old_capacity,
                                                array->capacity);
        }
        // Properly update the lines
        array->lines[array->count] = line;
        array->lineCount[array->count] = count;
        array->count++;

        return;
    }
}

//The memory management functions/macros I'm using here

#define GROW_CAPACITY(capacity) \
    ((capacity) < 8 ? 8 : (capacity) * 2)

#define GROW_ARRAY(previous, type, oldCount, count) \
    (type*) reallocate(previous, sizeof(type) * (oldCount), \
        sizeof(type) * (count))

void* reallocate(void* previous, size_t oldSize, size_t newSize) {
    // If size is null, erase it and get null_pointer
    if (newSize == 0) {
        free(previous);
        return NULL;
    }

    // reallocate the data into a new size
    // is Oldsize is zero :: malloc(data, newSize)
    return realloc(previous, newSize);
}
```

Comment: Could you post a main function similar to one you are trying to test with?

Comment: `#define GROW_ARRAY(previous, type, oldCount, count)` <<-- dont do this. Just dont

Comment: Please post a [example].